# how does sails.js handle database migrations when working with a schema database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I'm currently using `postgresql` for a database.

I come from more of a `rails` background where we create a migration and then run `rake db:migrate` to migrate the database.

How can I do something similar in `sails.js`?
Do I need to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With an unmodified `config/models.js` file each time you `sails lift` it will prompt you for one of 3 possible options, [detailed in the docs here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html):

1. `safe` -- No migrations are run
2. `alter` -- Sails will attempt to migrate the data as intelligently as possible
3. `drop` -- Sails will drop the database and run all of the migrations. 
             Equivalent to `rake db: drop db:migrate`

It's recommended that you only use `safe` in production, and run you migrations either by hand, or using one of the following modules (non-exhaustive list):

- https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate
- https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations

In development however you're generally safe to modify your `config/models.js` file to set the value of the `migrate` attribute to the `alter` setting.

Comment: Both mentioned migration libraries are no longer maintained.

Comment: But, only to reinforce: usually, an app that is already in production is still an app that is in development. So, after you "go live" with it, you'll need to adopt any good migration strategy and any framework would fit great. We can't be hostages of DBAs nowadays.